# The Sub Differential of a Matrix $ {L}_{1} $ Norm

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-optimization, machine-learning, subgradient

Given a matrix $ A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n} $ what is the Sub Differential (Sub Gradient) of

$$ g \left( A \right) = \lambda {\left\| A \right\|}_{1} $$

Comment: What is $m$? What is $T$? What is your definition of $\|\|_1$?

Comment: $m \times T$ is matrix dimension. $||_1$ is L1 norm of matrix.

Comment: @user2806363 given the ambiguity in the definition of $\|\cdot\|_1$ for matrices, I would suggest that you edit your question to make it _absolutely clear_ which norm you are referring to, providing an explicit formula.

Comment: @MichaelGrant I can't think of any context in which I've seen $\| A \|_{1}$ that isn't the norm induced by the vector 1-norm.  That 1-norm is simply the maximum of the columnwise sums of the absolute values of the entries.  What other norm is this notation used for?

Comment: @BrianBorchers I have seen it used to represent the one-norm of the vectorized matrix, but I agree that is not proper notation.

Comment: @BrianBorchers in matrix recovery problems where a regularizer promotes sparsity (e.g. in sparse-plus-low-rank decomposition problems), $\|\cdot\|_1$ usually means $\|A\|_1=\sum_{i,j}|a_{i,j}|$, i.e. the matrix is treated as if it were a vector

Answer (score 4):

There is a fair amount of ambiguity in what you're precisely referring to by $\|A\|_1$. I'll break it down into two possible cases.

**Case A**:

If you mean $\|A\|_1 = \|\text{vec}(A)\|_1$ for any tensor $A$, then WLOG assume $A$ is a vector $v$ of appropriate length.

Now, by definition, $\|v\|_1 := \sum_{j}|v_j|$, and by separability of the sum, we have $\partial \|v\|_1 = \Pi_{j}\partial |v_j| := \partial |v_1| \times \partial|v_2| \times \ldots $.

Thus it suffices to compute $\partial |u|$ for a scalar $u \in \mathbb R$.
Now, one can rewrite $|u| = \max \{zu | |z| \le 1\}$, and by the Bertsekas-Danskin Theorem for subdifferentials (Proposition A.22 of the PhD thesis of Bertsekas), we obtain
$$
\begin{split}
\partial |u| &= \text{conv}\{\nabla_u(zu) \mid z \in [-1, 1], zu = |u|\} = \text{conv}\{z \in [-1, 1] | zu = |u|\} \\
&= \begin{cases}[-1,1], &\mbox{ if }u = 0,\\
\text{sign}(u) := u/|u|,&\mbox{ otherwise.}\end{cases}
\end{split}
$$

For example, $\partial \|(-1, 0, 0, \pi)\|_1 = \{(-1, x, y, 1) | x, y \in [-1, 1]\}$.

**Case B: induced norm**

Here, $\|A\|_1 = \|A\|_{1,1} := \max_{\|x\|_1 \le 1} \|Ax\|_1$.

**Fact:**
*If $\varphi$ is a norm (on vectors, on matrices, etc.) with dual norm $\varphi^\star : a \mapsto \max_{\varphi(z) \le 1} \langle z, a \rangle$, and unit ball $B_*$ then*
$$
\partial \varphi(a) = \begin{cases}B_*, &\mbox{ if }a = 0,\\\{z \mid z \in B_*, \langle z, a\rangle = \varphi(a) \}, &\mbox{ otherwise.}\end{cases}
$$

This is an elementary consequence of the Bertsekas-Danskin Theorem.

Now, use the fact listed above to get

$$\partial \|A\|_1 = \{B \text{ s.t } \|B\|_\infty \le 1, \langle A, B\rangle_F = \|A\|_1\}.
$$

It's possible the above set can be made more explicit, but I didn't yet look into that.
Hope this all helps!

Comment: Thanks. but I didn't get the first part. why $||A||_1=||vec(A)||_1$ ? could you please elaborate on it more?

Comment: I would suggest it is _not_ obvious that $\|A\|_1$ is simply the sum of the absolute values. In fact, in my view, unless the author is clear, $\|A\|_1$ should be read as referring to the [_induced_ norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Induced_norm):
$$\|A\|_1 \triangleq \max_{x\neq 0}\|Ax\|_1/\|x\|_1 = \max_j \sum_i |a_{ij}|$$

Comment: Your definition from $||A||_1$ is write. then how I can compute sub-differential of it ?

Comment: @Michael Grant: Good point. OK, then the OP should rewrite their norm as $\|A\|_{1,1}$ to mean the induced-norm you're referring to.

Comment: That is by no means necessary. The use of $\|A\|_1$ to refer to the induced norm has been standard for a long time, and indeed I would suggest that the only reason the elementwise one-norm interpretation is popular today is because of the rise in low-rank approximation methods.

Comment: I've no problem agreeing your remark. In any case, *explicit is better than implicit*  :)

Comment: Thanks for expanding your answer!

Comment: I have confusion with your derivation for the case of \textbf{Case A}. why you sudanly changed the variable names from $A$ to $u$ ? Second: would it be correct to write $\partial |V|= \sum_{j}V_j$ ?