# The Sub Differnetial of the Induced $ {L}_{1} $ Matrix Norm and the $ {L}_{2} $ Norm of a Vector

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, subgradient

I have 
 $$g(W)=\lambda ||W||_1 + \gamma \sum_{i=1}^{k} ||w_i||_2$$
 where $W \in R^{m \times T}, ||W||_1=max_j \sum_{j=1}^{T}|a_{ij}|$ and $w_i \in R^T$.
I know that, $$\partial (\gamma \sum_{i=1}^{k} ||w_i||_2)=\gamma \sum_{i=1}^{k} \frac{w_i}{||w_i||_2}, w_i \neq0$$
 $$\partial (\gamma \sum_{i=1}^{k} ||w_i||_2)=?, w_i =0$$

I would like drive the sub-differential of this term. I was wondering whether someone can help me with this ?

Comment: This should help: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2044993/how-to-compute-sub-differential-of-matrix-l1-norm

Comment: Yes, but it's get bite tricky by second term.

Comment: Well, subgradients do add...

Comment: I would like to compute the proximal operator of whole term, so I was trying to write down the optimality condition for that. Now I'm stuck with driving sub-differential part $g(W)$. would you please help me to write down the proximal operator of this term?