# Sub-differential of $||A \circ X||_1$ w.r.t $X$

Tags: matrices, derivatives

Let $A$ and $X$ be two rectangular matrices where the elements of $A$ are non-negative.
. What is the subdifferential of $||A\circ X||_1$ with respect to $X$. 
Is it $A \circ \Gamma$ where $\gamma_{ij} = sign(x_{ij})$ if $x_{ij} \neq 0$ and $[-1, 1]$ otherwise?

Note: $||B||_1 = \sum_{ij}|b_{ij}|$

Comment: Why don't you try it on some simple cases, say with both $A$ and $X$ being $2\times 2$, or even $X$ being $2\times 1$. Write out everything carefully, term-by-term instead of using summation notation. Apply the definition of the subdifferential, and see what you get. Also note that $$\frac{d}{dt}|t|$$ is undefined at $t = 0$. It is *not* "$[-1,1]$".

Comment: Your expression for the subdifferential looks correct for $x_{ij}\ne 0$.

Comment: @PaulSinclair: I had a look at this post: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2044993/how-to-compute-sub-differential-of-matrix-l1-norm. Don't I have to follow the same steps as in here? If so why I can't use the fact that $\gamma = [-1, 1]$ when $x = 0$.