# compute the subgradient set of $\max(x,0)$ using Danskin

Tags: convex-analysis, subgradient, non-smooth-analysis

I'd like to compute the subgradient set of $f(x):=\max(x,0)$ using [Danskin's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Danskin%27s_theorem), similar to what is done [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2046091/334300).
We have
\begin{align}
f(x) = \max(x,0) = \max\{\phi(x,z): z\in Z\}
\end{align}
where we must choose $\phi(x,z)$ and the compact set $Z$ appropriately.

Let $\phi(x,z) = z\cdot x$ and take $Z = [{\color{red}{c}},1]$ where we start with, say, ${\color{red}{c}} = -5$.
By testing $x<0$, we see that we must take $c=0$ in order for $\phi(x,z)=f(x)$ to hold.
Then for the active set $Z_0(x) = \{z^*:\phi(x,z^*) = \max_{z\in Z}\phi(x,z)\},$ we have
\begin{align}
\partial f(x) &= \mathrm{conv} \Big\{ \frac{\partial \phi(x,z)}{\partial x} : z \in Z_0(x)\Big\}\\
&= \mathrm{conv} \{z : z\in Z_0(x)\}\\
&= \begin{cases}
\{1\}, &\text{if $x>0$}\\
[0,1], &\text{if $x=0$}\\
\{0\}, &\text{if $x<0$}.
\end{cases}
\end{align}
Is there a better way to set $c$ besides "guess and check"? Are there rules for choosing $\phi$?

Comment: Why not using $Z=\{0,1\}$ ? Also $Z$ should not contain negative numbers.

Comment: @daw: I think $Z$ should be $[0,1]$, not $\{0,1\}$, right? My question is how would we know to use $[0,1]$ in the first place? It's clear for this problem, but I'm wondering if there is a more general technique to convert a function $f$ into $\phi$ and $Z$ to use Danskin

Comment: Well, becuase with $Z = [0,1]$, you have $\max(x,0) = \max_{z \in Z} z\cdot x$.